# Printing outputs from multiple looping input

Tags: c

I'm sorry for the weird title but english isnt my first language so I don't know how to make it specific.
I just learned coding for 2 weeks, so I'm a total newbie in this subject.

So, let get started with my problem.

this is what I'm supposed to program. [image: Correct Output]

But so far, this is what I can do. [image: My Ouput]

and this is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
int main() {

float stud_total;
float stud_score;
char stud_name[50];
float stud_total_score = 0;
char max_name[50] = "test";
float max_score = 55;
float min_score = 50;
float avg_score;
char temp_name[50] = "dwdw";

//Start of Total Student between 2-10 looping
do {

    printf("Input Total Student [2..10] : ");
    scanf("%f", &stud_total);fflush(stdin);
} while (stud_total < 2 || stud_total>10);
//end of Total student looping
printf("\n");


//Start Name & Score Input Looping
for (int i = 1;i <= stud_total;i++) {

    do {
        printf("Input Name for Student %d [3..50] : ", i);
        scanf("%s", stud_name);fflush(stdin);
    } while (strlen(stud_name) < 3 || strlen(stud_name) > 50);

    do {
        printf("Input Score for Student %d [0..100] : ", i);
        scanf("%f", &stud_score);fflush(stdin);
    } while (stud_score < 0 || stud_score>100);

    if (stud_score < max_score) {
        min_score = stud_score;
        memset(min_name, '\0', sizeof(min_name));
        strcpy(stud_name, stud_name);
        strcpy(min_name, stud_name);
    }
    else if (stud_score >= min_score) {
        max_score = stud_score;
        memset(max_name, '\0', sizeof(max_name));
        strcpy(stud_name, stud_name);
        strcpy(max_name, stud_name);
    }

    stud_total_score = stud_total_score + stud_score;

    memset(temp_name, '\0', sizeof(temp_name));
    strcpy(stud_name, stud_name);
    strcpy(temp_name, stud_name);
}

//Math part
avg_score = stud_total_score / stud_total;
//END of Name & Score Input Looping

    //Start of Score Table

for (int k = 1;k <= 50;++k) {
    printf("-");
}
printf("\n%-4s %-32s %3s\n", "No.", "Nama", "Nilai");

for (int k = 1;k <= 50;++k) {
    printf("-");
}
for (int j = 1;j <= stud_total;++j) {
    printf("\n%-4d %-32s %3.2f", j, temp_name, stud_score);
}



//END of Score Table 




//Start of conlusion
printf("\n");
printf("\n");
printf("Highest score is %.2f achieved by %s\n", max_score, max_name);
printf("Lowest score is %.2f obtained by %s \n", min_score, min_name);
printf("Student Average : %.2f", avg_score);

//end of conclusion



getchar();
getchar();
return 0;}
```

My question is, how do I make the table so that the input from inside the looping can be printed after the looping?

or if you have better idea please tell me.

I've tried putting the table inside the loop but it doesn't help at all as you may already know.

Comment: This is not C++ and it is not C#, so please do not tag either. If your code is only relevant to C, then only tag C.

Comment: Don't spam tags... C++ , C# , and C are **not** the same language

Comment: You're not declaring min_name anywhere?

Comment: You need to store the data in an array or arrays during the input stage so that you still have all of it during the output stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, what you want to do is first get number of students, then get their name and marks, finally compute avg, max, min etc, right?

Best approach is using structures. Since you are new, what you can do is:

1. Create a 2d array of chars:

   ```
   char name[100][100], marks[100].
   ```
2. Get number of students in a variable `n`.
3. Use a loop to get names and marks:

   ```
   for(i=0;i < n;i++){scanf("%s",name[i]);}
   scanf("%d",marks[i]);
   ```
4. Now you can print it using the same loop, change scanf to printf.
5. For avg, max and min, iterate through marks, like:

   ```
   marks = 0;
   for(i=0;i< n;i++){sum = sum + marks[i];}
   printf("%d",marks);
   ```

Comment: Thanks!!! although i didnt use the code, i got the main idea and able to finish my assignment!! thanksss alot

Comment: you are welcome. :) If you think this solved the issue, can you mark it as solution?

Comment: This is basically a good answer, but on principle I won't upvote any C answer which doesn't guard against buffer overflow. Your are not using `scanf` safely. OP also used in unsafely, but this error should be pointed out rather than replicated.

Comment: @JohnColeman :) Yes, you are right. Are you saying about the condition check that (n<100) ?

Comment: Yes, you are right that `n <= 100` isn't checked, but the issue that jumped out at me is that `scanf("%s",name[i]);` would overflow the buffer if a user enters a very large string as a name. Such a string would be far larger than any actual name, but the `scanf` function itself (since you didn't specify any field width) will happily transfer as many characters as you feed it, and put them somewhere in memory, even if doing so either triggers a seg fault or overwrites other data.

Comment: @JohnColeman I guess fgets(name[i], 100, stdin) will do it, won't it?

Comment: That will guard against the overflow, but will leave `\n` with the string. These things are hard to get right (C is quite annoying that way). For non-production quality code, something like (untested) `names[i][strlen(names[i])-1] = '\0'` should suffice. The point isn't to go out of the way to make a Stack Overflow answer bullet-proof, so much as to make beginners aware of the issue and to (hopefully) get them in the habit of guarding against buffer overflow.

Comment: Yes, you are so right. Even I have never thought about this. Just now I realized what a mistake I was making. Thanks a ton. Let me code and see, if I come up with a decent solution, I'll make an edit. :)